# Verify that an Object has a certain tag/property and if so, perform code based on that property

Tags: vb.net

I am creating program in which your character must make his way along a maze.

How do I stop him from moving through the walls? (Both the walls and the character are picture boxes). i.e. when you press the Up key, [if there is a wall in front of him,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k4SA.png) he doesn't move. At the moment, my code only changes the X and Y values of the picture box, so the character moves on top of the wall/through the wall. This is in Visual Basic 2010. Is there a way to scan the tag of the picture box and if it is of a cerain value, not move?
My code for movement so far is:

```
    Private Sub frmLevel1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If Tag <= 2 Then
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Up
                picP1.Top -= 36
            Case Keys.Right
                picP1.Left += 36
            Case Keys.Down
                picP1.Top += 36
            Case Keys.Left
                picP1.Left -= 36
            Case Keys.W
                picP2.Top -= 36
            Case Keys.D
                picP2.Left += 36
            Case Keys.S
                picP2.Top += 36
            Case Keys.A
                picP2.Left -= 36
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

This moves the character 1 grid space in the direction pressed.
I also have a timer that stops the character from moving past the outer borders:

```
    Private Sub tmrBorders_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrBorders.Tick
    If picP1.Left <= 39 Then
        picP1.Left += 36
    End If
    If picP1.Left >= 583 Then
        picP1.Left -= 36
    End If
    If picP1.Top <= 83 Then
        picP1.Top += 36
    End If
    If picP1.Top >= 445 Then
        picP1.Top -= 36
    End If
    If picP2.Left <= 39 Then
        picP2.Left += 36
    End If
    If picP2.Left >= 583 Then
        picP2.Left -= 36
    End If
    If picP2.Top <= 83 Then
        picP2.Top += 36
    End If
    If picP2.Top >= 445 Then
        picP2.Top -= 36
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm just having problems for the inner borders. Is there possibly a way to reverse the direction of movement? or maybe record the last space that the character was on?

Comment: You should probably add some code to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to MSDN inheritance explanation: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx

Maybe something like this?

Instead of using a standard picture box, create your own class which inherits from the picturebox.

```
   Public Class MYPICBOX
inherits picturebox

end class
```

then add someproperties to it to show it as impassable

```
   Public Class MYPICBOX
inherits picturebox
Property IsImpassable as Boolean = true
end class
```

Populate your world with the MYPICBOX class inplace of picturebox

Now test if you can move through it

```
 Sub MoveIfNoCollision(spriteToMove as mypicbox, Xmovement as integer, YMovement as integer)



           'Variable to determine if the actual movement routine should be called
           collision = False
'for this next bit of code, you should use something like a rectangle to artificially expand the bounds of the
'sprite to move and perform your check using it instead of the sprite to move object.
'or you could move it, run this check and then move it back if 
'a collision is detected. 
             'check each mypicbox that is not the one targeted for movement
            For Each pb as mypicbox In Me.Controls
             If pb IsNot spriteToMove AndAlso spriteToMove.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pb.Bounds) andalso pb.impassable Then
             'shouldn't move, mark it as failed and end the sub
             collision = True
            Exit For
            end if
           Next
        IF collision = false
             'safe to move. Call the actual move routine
             MoveSpriteAndUpdateImage(spriteToMove, Xmovement, YMovement)
        end if
        end sub
```

EDIT:

```
    Sub MoveSpriteAndUpdateImage(spriteToMove as mypicbox, Xmovement as integer, YMovement as integer)
'do stuff if needed prior to moving

'Move
 spriteToMove.location = New Point(spriteToMove.location.X + XMovement, spriteToMove.location.Y + Ymovement)


'do stuff if needed after moving

endsub
```

Comment: How should I declare the MoveSpriteAndUpdateImage?

Comment: Sorry for being annoying, but do i change the class of the current picture boxes to MYPICBOX? in not, how do I populate the world With that class?

Comment: @TrollKirby : Yes you switch all existing PictureBoxes to the custom one,

Comment: @VisualVincent Any ideas on how I would do that?

Comment: @TrollKirby : Open the .Designer.vb file and search for `PictureBox` and replace all you want replaced?

Comment: @I'mStartingToHateThisSite How do I switch all pictureboxes to the Custom picture Box

Comment: Sorry guy, but the best information that I can give you right now is that you have a little bit of reading to do on the concepts of object oriented scripting.  Here is a link to read up on the concept of inheritance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx

Comment: and also, like Visual Vincent said, you can use the search tool to find and replace everything in the designer file from picturebox to mypicbox.

Comment: I somewhat assumed that you were managing the picturebox placement form code instead of the U.I.  Don't forget to rebuild the solution to make the new class available in the tool box if you plan on doing any drag and drop stuff.